# How to apply value based on qty

Tags: sql-server-2017

Manufacturing based business. We have jobs with material allocations. I have  jobs with the same material required but not enough stock on hand to fulfil all those requirements.

I have 10 on hand. How is SQL can I apply in this example the qty the first 10 jobs based on the job delivery date where the AllocCompleted is N. I want to call the field SoftAlloc. I want to see both the completed and non complete allocations.

| Job | Material | QtyReq | QtyIss | SoftAlloc | JobDate | AlloCompleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2022-02-28 | N |
| 110 | 3205 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-02-28 | Y |
| 120 | 3205 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-02-28 | Y |
| 200 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2022-02-28 | N |
| 300 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2022-02-28 | N |
| 310 | 3205 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-02-28 | Y |
| 320 | 3205 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-02-28 | Y |
| 400 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2022-02-28 | N |
| 500 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2022-03-15 | N |
| 540 | 3205 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-03-15 | Y |
| 550 | 3205 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-03-15 | Y |
| 600 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2022-03-20 | N |
| 700 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2022-03-20 | N |
| 800 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2022-03-22 | N |
| 900 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2022-04-28 | N |
| 920 | 3205 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-04-28 | Y |
| 930 | 3205 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-04-28 | Y |
| 940 | 3205 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-04-28 | Y |
| 1000 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2022-05-28 | N |
| 1100 | 3205 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2022-06-28 | N |

```
declare @QtyOnHand int = 10;

select *,
       SoftAlloc = case when AllocCompleted <> 'Y' AND sum(QtyReq) over (order by JobDate) <= @QtyOnHand
                        then QtyReq
                        when AllocCompleted <> 'Y' sum(QtyReq) over (order by JobDate) - QtyReq <= @QtyOnHand
                        then @QtyOnHand - sum(QtyReq) over (order by JobDate) + QtyReq
                        else 0
                        end
from   jobs
```

Comment: is `QtyReq` always 1 ?

Comment: Hi, no it is not but they are always whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

use `sum(QtyReq) over (order by JobDate)` to create a running total of `QtyReq` and compare with the `QtyOnHand`. The allocation decision is handle by case expression

```
declare @QtyOnHand int = 10;

select *,
       SoftAlloc = case when sum(QtyReq) over (order by JobDate) <= @QtyOnHand
                        then QtyReq
                        when sum(QtyReq) over (order by JobDate) - QtyReq <= @QtyOnHand
                        then @QtyOnHand - sum(QtyReq) over (order by JobDate) + QtyReq
                        else 0
                        end
from   jobs
```

Note : in the fiddle, it is using an identity column to simulate the `JobDate` sequence

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=85bd3d553a5538865f6657c67b075cd3)

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. (when applying filters on AllocCompleted <> 'Y')

But jobs that have not been issued are mixed with jobs that have been. SoftAlloc is being assigned against those job that have been issued.

Comment: Added  AllocCompleted < 'Y' in case statement and didn't work.

Comment: There was no requirement on `AllocCompleted` in your original question

Comment: Update your question with the query that you used and include the addition information about `AllocCompleted`

Comment: Updated with additional information.

Comment: please also show your query that does not work

Comment: I have posted the query I was using.

Comment: `AllocComplete <> 'Y'` should be at the `WHERE` clause